# How to import csv file with qoutations over multiple rows?

Tags: r, csv, import, quoting

I am reading in a bunch of .csv files containing mainly speech. The files are formatted in a way that a qoutation of one speaker goes over multiple rows. How do i need to set my qoutation settings in read.csv to correctly import them?

i tried to import them via:

```
AlleProtokolleSafe <- list() 
listcsv <- dir(path = "Plenarprotokolle/", pattern = "*.csv")
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  AlleProtokolleSafe[[k]] <- read.csv(paste(c("Plenarprotokolle/", listcsv[k]), sep = "", collapse = ""), sep = ",", header = FALSE, quote = "", encoding = "UTF-8")
}
```

The problem is now that as i disabled qoutes, "," in texts will be read as seperators, altough they shouldnt, as they are in speech. If i instead do qoute = "\"" some files wont get read in correctly, too. I guess because there is a quotation starting in a row and finishing in another row.

i use the datasets from https://github.com/Datenschule/offenesparlament-data/tree/master/sessions/csv. If you look at 162.csv for example you can see the qoutation starting in row 2 and ending in row 52.

Note that header = FALSE as it somehow gives an error if TRUE and qoute="".
I dont need the headers so i can easily remove the first row afterwards.

i just want to import plain text for a word-analysis and thus i plan on trowing everything else of these dataset away. Is there a better way to so?

EDIT: Still having a problem here: Imoprting all of the Datasets i get 15 columns and various rows except for Nr. 162 and 191, there i only get 3 columns. Can somebody explain that by looking into the files? i cant see a real difference there and i am not really into .csv

Comment: I read the file you indicated with `read.csv` with the default parameters and I didn't face any problems, but then again I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve.
You say it does not matter for you who said the quotes or where or anything, you just want the text, right? and what kind of data structure are you thinking of here? how would you output look like?

Comment: Idealy i just like the plain text from column 11, not the noise in the other columns. The problem with the quotations and "," is that they shift the columns. Finally i want all entries in the original column 11 in one giant string.

Comment: If i use the standard read.csv command 191.csv gets added with only one row, although it should have plenty

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, understand your question correctly.

My Answer is using `data.table::fread` and `dplyr`.

I prepared two option.

First option is save data like data.frame in list

Second option is unlist and concat all the strings in list

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

AlleProtokolleSafe <- list() # This is First option
AlleProtokolleSafe_un <- list() # This is Second option

listcsv = file.path("Your directory path",
                    list.files("Your directory path", pattern = '.csv'))

for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  AlleProtokolleSafe[[k]] <- fread(listcsv[k],encoding = "UTF-8", select = 'text')
  AlleProtokolleSafe_un[[k]] <- fread(listcsv[k],encoding = "UTF-8", select = 'text') %>% 
    sapply(., paste, collapse=" ")
}
```

From the above code option `select='text'` in `fread` means just load `text` column ( I think you want this column. Is it right? )

Finally, you can get result below

```
> AlleProtokolleSafe[[1]][1]
   1: Einen wundersch?nen sonnigen guten........Bundesminister Hermann Gr?he.
> AlleProtokolleSafe_un[[1]]
   # You will get all the text in listcsv[1] with one row
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me. Using select text i get the error "Column name 'text' not found in column name header (case sensitive), skipping."  and using select 11 (which is the column number of text) i get "Column number 11 (select[1]) is too large for this table, which only has 3 columns." The results seem fine tho, except it stops with bothz select values right before the above mentioned file 162. somewhat in that file must be strange to read

Comment: Well, i now somewhat got a solution. The code you provided reads in all files correct except for 2 files, which i now manipulate manually to get it read in correctly too. Thanks